# Emmet nesting content under sibling divs with different class names

Tags: html, sublimetext3, emmet

I'm trying to understand how I can use shorthand syntax to make two sibling `div`s each contain the same content

```
section#container>row>(div.columns.small-4.small-offset-1+div.columns.small-4)>p
```

is not working. I'd like a structure like

```
<section id="container">
    <row>
        <div class="columns small-4 small-offset-1">
            <p></p>
        </div>
        <div class="columns small-4">
            <p></p>
        </div>
    </row>
</section>
```

but instead the `p` is appended as a sibling to the `div`s:

```
<section id="container">
    <row>
        <div class="columns small-4 small-offset-1"></div>
        <div class="columns small-4"></div>
        <p></p>
    </row>
</section>
```

What syntax will achieve this? I'm hoping for something shorter than following each div with the `>p` as this will become very redundant as the internal structure grows more complex.

Answer (score 0):

Such feature is not available in Emmet and I think it won’t be available in future. Instead of writing one large expression with complex structure consider writing a few short expressions

Answer (score 0):

if you wanted something like this in vs code using emmet abbreviations

```
    <div class="parent">
        <div class="child">
            <div class="box-a">
                <button id="button1">
                </button>
            </div>
            <div class="box-b">
                <button id="button2">
                </button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

this will work use `^` to create sibling element

```
.parent>.child>.box-a>button#button1^.box-b>button#button2
```

as for your structure this is it

```
section.parent>row>.columns.small-4.small-offset-1>p^.columns.small-4>p
```

```
    <section class="parent">
        <row>
            <div class="columns small-4 small-offset-1">
                <p></p>
            </div>
            <div class="columns small-4">
                <p></p>
            </div>
        </row>
    </section>
```